# Why does Python use py to run programs on Windows

Tags: python

I have a python script that is run like this:

```
python3 script.py
```

This works fine on Linux and Mac. However it doesn't on Windows. Comments I've read, and the [official Windows FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html) recommend using this instead on Windows:

```
py -3 script.py
```

But the FAQ doesn't explain *why*. Why does Windows have a unique execution method, and why is it [*only* for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher)?

Do I really need to resort to this sort of ugly hackery?

```
if (windows)
   run("py -3 script.py")
else
   run("python3 script.py")
```

Comment: on windows, I am able to use `python script.py`...

Comment: For what purpose and in what language is your hackery written?

Comment: If you install Python from the Microsoft store, python3 should work. See https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Comment: Same over here. I can use `python` and `python3` as commands on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Are you launching subprocesses in a python script? If so, just use `sys.executable` (to use the same executable that launched the parent script).

Comment: The documentation changed from `python` to `py` in v3.6 – but no reason was provided. I run `python` just like everybody else. But maybe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: `py` should give you the *python launcher*, which isn't the same thing as the python executable. The launcher chooses an executable for you, from potentially different versions available on your system. Both can be in your path. [Here's the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) for describing why the python launcher exists in the first place (to allow scripts to use a shebang line, with the intent of allowing the script itself to choose the executable in Windows, in case you might need different versions of python for different scripts)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Ah thanks, this is the most useful answer!